# Conditional Formatting for Linked Cells. LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I wish to format cell if it was pasted with link to another sheet.
How to define if cell is linked?

I go to **Format** » Conditional Formatting. 
**Condition 1** is **Formula**. `=IF(...` and I'm stuck =)

Comment: You can check if it's a link (reference), by using the formula `=ISREF(<current cell address>)`, replacing `<current cell address>` with the address of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

For example, start with this, where sheets are named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2":

[image: formulas]

Then in conditional formatting, choose `Formula is`.  Use [SEARCH](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SEARCH) and [FORMULA](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#FORMULA):

```
SEARCH("Sheet", FORMULA(A1))
```

[image: conditional formatting dialog]

Giving this result:

[image: result]